# What causes a rollback failed error in mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, doctrine

I get the following error when I try to perform a rollback.

> Rollback failed. There is no active transaction.

I searched for this issue and found a few suggestions that recommend disabling the autocommit setting. But I am unsure how to do this. Is there any other reason for the above error? I am using MYSQL and Zend and my php.ini file loaded the required drivers.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL works in autocommit by default. You can turn it off with:

```
$connection->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, false);
```

Another idea I have is you didn't start the transaction (which should disable autocommit in Doctrine):

```
$connection->beginTransaction();
```

Comment: i couldn't understand how to post code in a comment so just posted as an answer

Comment: @jakub-zalas In which Symfony version is this setAttribute supported?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Symfony. The question was about doctrine1.

Comment: This was helpful enough to help me with Symfony and Doctrine.

$manager->getConnection()->setAutoCommit(0);

Answer (score 1):

The class **UnitOfWork.php** has a catch block like:

```
catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->em->close();
            $conn->rollback();

            throw $e;
}
```

Of course, if your class is not ready to find an already closed entity manager and therefore connection, you will have this exception. The worst thing about it is that it masks the underlying cause of the exception, since the error was caused before the catch block being executed. To fix it, you can do a simple check in your class' catch block:

```
catch(Exception $e) {
    if($conn->isTransactionActive()) {
         [rollback]
         [close]
         [rethrow] (if necessary)
    }

}
```

Comment: +1. Shouldn't `[rethrow]` be outside the if statement? That way the exception will always be rethrown, even if there is no active transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.....I have called rollback() function 2 times in different places in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the transaction exists with transaction nesting level:

```
$this->em->getConnection()->getTransactionNestingLevel()
```

If nesting level exist grather than 0, then you can do a rollback